# Filling in Third Party Login Screen Programmatically Utilizing Powershell Script

Tags: powershell

I am interested in speeding up my development/testing workflow on a program that I am debugging. I am developing in VB6, and have written a PS1 script to move my DLLs accordingly, but I want to go a step further.

My testing workflow involves opening the program, which has a login screen, launched by ThirdPartyLoginScreen.exe. Is there any way to programmatically pass login information to this EXE using PowerShell, or am I confined to writing it in VB6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your script starts the program ThirdPartyLoginScreen.exe, and that program comes to the foreground, then a lightweight way to do this is to use [SendKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx).

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

# start the program
ThirdParytLoginScreen.exe

# send keystrokes to the foreground window
[Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('domain\username')
[Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('{TAB}')
[Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('p@ssw0rd1')
[Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('{ENTER}')
```

This is the simplest way to do basic UI automation through powershell.  It has numerous drawbacks and limitations, but it might help get you unblocked for simple scenarios.

Comment: Thanks. You put me on the right track. In addition to System.Windows.Forms, I also had to add `Microsoft.VisualBasic`. After I called the exe, I also had to use `[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate("ProcessName")` and then everything else was golden.